# Basic <ul> sub-menu not visible on page

Tags: html, css

I have a basic horizontal html menu with a structure similar to this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
       Menu item 1
       <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>Sub item 1</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu item 2</li>
</ul>
```

Please see for http://jsfiddle.net/4EmJ9/ for full example. (The menu in question contains the text Bernalillo)

The problem: `.sub-menu` is completely hidden. I can see it is positioned correctly (using inspect element), and I have also played with z-index and container heights, but to no avail.

Constraint: I can change **ONLY** css. The HTML (which may make you cry) is locked up in Sharepoint until the end of time. Editing Javascript is out too.

Any thoughts as to how to make the sub menu show up?

Comment: I wish all questions looked more like this. Simple code examples, constraints and the problem easily distinguishable. Had to work with SharePoint myself, I feel you. Good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/4EmJ9/2/

you had some `overflow: hidden` on 2 parent elements. I have updated your css.

```
.customNav {
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
    height: 30px;
    background: #5e5e5e;
}

.s4-tn {
    margin-left: 0px;
    /*overflow: hidden; */
    height: 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how much you can change the css but here's a quick example I just wrote:

[JSFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/vEA4a/3/)

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li>
       Menu item 1
       <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li>Sub item 1</li>
       </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Menu item 2</li>
</ul>


ul{margin:0;padding:0;}

.menu > li
{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    margin-left:15px;
}

.sub-menu
{
    display:none;
}

.sub-menu li
{
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
}

.menu li:hover .sub-menu
{
    display:block;
}
```

I know it's not much but hopefully it will point you in the right direction...

Comment: I appreciate the effort, and while I'm sure this a great solution, the answer to my problem was the incorrect `overflow` styles. Cheers!